# Wrong Calculation in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hi i have problem a wrong calculation in visual basic

when i input 1.5 all in the combo boxes then

the `textbox4.text`to `textbox14.text` are the units that has the values of 3,3,3,3,3,3,6,2,3 that is equal to 29.

I add all from `textbox30.text`to `textbox22.text` the divide them to the total units that is 29
the `textbox31.text` is equal to 1.51724137931034 but the correct value is 1.50
like this

```
    TextBox30.Text = 3*1.5
    TextBox29.Text = 3*1.5
    TextBox28.Text = 3*1.5
    TextBox27.Text = 3*1.5
    TextBox26.Text = 3*1.5
    TextBox25.Text = 3*1.5
    TextBox24.Text = 6*1.5
    TextBox23.Text = 2*1.5
    TextBox22.Text = 3*1.5
```

a = 4.5 + 4.5 + 4.5 + 4.5 + 4.5 + 4.5 + 9 + 3 + 4.5

textbox31.text = a/29

heres the code

```
Dim a As Integer
    TextBox30.Text = TextBox4.Text * ComboBox5.Text
    TextBox29.Text = TextBox5.Text * ComboBox6.Text
    TextBox28.Text = TextBox6.Text * ComboBox7.Text
    TextBox27.Text = TextBox7.Text * ComboBox8.Text
    TextBox26.Text = TextBox8.Text * ComboBox9.Text
    TextBox25.Text = TextBox9.Text * ComboBox10.Text
    TextBox24.Text = TextBox10.Text * ComboBox11.Text
    TextBox23.Text = TextBox11.Text * ComboBox12.Text
    TextBox22.Text = TextBox12.Text * ComboBox13.Text


    a = TextBox30.Text + Val(TextBox29.Text) + Val(TextBox28.Text) + Val(TextBox27.Text) + Val(TextBox26.Text) + Val(TextBox25.Text) + Val(TextBox24.Text) + Val(TextBox23.Text) + Val(TextBox22.Text)

    TextBox31.Text = (a / 29)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it solve your problem, but it's always better to use a datatype like double for decimals. Integer is just for whole numbers.

So try `Dim a As Double`

Comment: thanks you!
I am using materialskin from nuget package thats why i cant use `Dim a As Double`
so rather than double i use `Dim a as System.Double`

Comment: @Hawiie13 : FYI `Double` and `System.Double` are the exact same thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

a is an integer.  a = 44.  a/29 = 1.5172413793.

Can avoid some of these problems by ensuring option strict is always on.